# The formula using Network days function in excel is not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The below formula is giving me the result as `#value`! Can anyone please share the updated formula ?

Formula;

```
Map(Details[Date1],Details[Date2],LAMBDA(start,end, NETWORKDAYS(start,end)))
```

2. I need one more formula.
   I need to use `today()` in the place of `Date2`

Comment: How do you know the problem is with `NETWORKDAYS`?

Comment: I need to know how to use the function network days  in excel

Comment: So replace Date2 with today() and see what happens. What error do you get? What did you check?

Comment: Have you checked the explanation that Excel provides? comes with examples.

Comment: This is not working Map(Details[Date1],Details[Date2], LAMBDA(start,end, NETWORKDAYS(start,end))).

Comment: @Maddy I tested the following: `=MAP(A1:A2, B1:B2, LAMBDA(a,b, NETWORKDAYS(a,b)))` and it works, are you sure your input data is in date data type? an error of type `#VALUE!` is usually a data type issue. This is what the documentation says. *"If any argument is not a valid date, NETWORKDAYS returns the #VALUE! error value."*, probably you have the dates in text data type

Comment: The columns are in date format only. Thanks for the formula, but I need to use on a table level, here Details is the table name and date 1 and date 2 are columns.

Comment: Can you share some sample data that is in this table so that we can replicate. In it's current form, we aren't able to replicate the same error with your function. If we can't replicate then we are only guessing at why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Date1 has 12/23/2021 Date2 has 12/30/2021. I tested with one value, even then it failed. Both are date data types

Comment: I'm also not able to replicate using your exact formula (using table references). It really does sound like what you have is something that looks like a date, in that the cell literally says "12/23/2021" but excel is not recognizing that as an actual date. In your worksheet, clear out the value and type in `2021-12-23` and `2021-12-31` and see it clears up.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the #VALUE error because my region uses dd/mm/yyyy, so 12/23/2021 is not a valid date. What is your region setting? What happens if you try using 12/10/2021 and 12/12/2021?

Comment: I changed to these dates. I am still getting the error as #value!

Comment: To test the text theory, try converting the values to date `=MAP(Details[Date1],Details[Date2],LAMBDA(start,end, NETWORKDAYS(DATEVALUE(start),DATEVALUE(end))))`

Comment: This resulted #value!

Comment: @Maddy Are you using an English-language version of Excel?

Comment: Yes, I just checked

Comment: The number format of an Excel cell can be "date" even if the contents of that cell is "text". Try the following formula:  all returns should be `FALSE_FALSE`.  `=MAP(Details[Date1],Details[Date2],LAMBDA(start,end, TEXTJOIN("_",,ISTEXT(start),ISTEXT(end))))`

Comment: Try creating a new workbook, just copy one set of Date1 and Date2, paste them as values in the new workbook, and try just `NETWORKDAYS` in the new workbook. Maybe the issue is with your current workbook?

Comment: Also might help if you take 3 screenshots of the formula bar while you have Date1, Date2, and your formula selected.

Comment: @Maddy at this point the best course of action is for you to share the file (share the link), so we can take a look at it, please share it with edit permission. Thanks

Comment: Hi all, thank you all for your responses. I got the answer for my query.